# \linegoal: its use in the second column of the two column document doesn't work correctly

Tags: equations, linegoal

This is the following-up question to interesting @Bernard [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484009/line-spreads-and-mixes-with-next-column/484012?). For some reason I test his interesting solution, how it works if i repeat the same equation four times:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
NUP_S
    & =1- \rlap{\parbox[t]{\linegoal}{probability of successfully finishing an SU service}}\\[0.5ex]
    & = 1 - \frac{\lambda_S(1-P^{BL}_S)(1-P^{FT}_S)}{\lambda_S}\\
    & = P^{BL}_S + P^{FT}_S + P^{BL}_S  P^{FT}_S\\
NUP_S
    & = P^{BL}_S + P^{FT}_S - P^{BL}_S  P^{FT}_S
\end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
\lipsum[2]
    \begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
NUP_S
    & =1- \rlap{\parbox[t]{\linegoal}{probability of successfully finishing an SU service}}\\[0.5ex]
    & = 1 - \frac{\lambda_S(1-P^{BL}_S)(1-P^{FT}_S)}{\lambda_S}\\
    & = P^{BL}_S + P^{FT}_S + P^{BL}_S  P^{FT}_S\\
NUP_S
    & = P^{BL}_S + P^{FT}_S - P^{BL}_S  P^{FT}_S
\end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
\lipsum[3]
    \begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
NUP_S
    & =1- \rlap{\parbox[t]{\linegoal}{probability of successfully finishing an SU service}}\\[0.5ex]
    & = 1 - \frac{\lambda_S(1-P^{BL}_S)(1-P^{FT}_S)}{\lambda_S}\\
    & = P^{BL}_S + P^{FT}_S + P^{BL}_S  P^{FT}_S\\
NUP_S
    & = P^{BL}_S + P^{FT}_S - P^{BL}_S  P^{FT}_S
\end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
\lipsum[4-5]
    \begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
NUP_S
    & =1- \rlap{\parbox[t]{\linegoal}{probability of successfully finishing an SU service}}\\[0.5ex]
    & = 1 - \frac{\lambda_S(1-P^{BL}_S)(1-P^{FT}_S)}{\lambda_S}\\
    & = P^{BL}_S + P^{FT}_S + P^{BL}_S  P^{FT}_S\\
NUP_S
    & = P^{BL}_S + P^{FT}_S - P^{BL}_S  P^{FT}_S
\end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
\lipsum[6]
\end{document}
```

**Edited:**

To my surprise, the results of equation code  (after two compilation) are not the same as expected. Each equation in the second column on the page has different formatted text:

[image]

I wonder, do I overlooked something in my test or the reasons is in some difference in used LaTeX installation. I use 64-bit MikTeX, upgraded yesterday.

Comment: The fact that the equation is doubled is irrelevant. The problem seems to be in that the second equation is in the right column. If I remove the first display and substitute it with a `\lipsum` paragraph, the output is similar to yours.

Comment: I tested it also with `multicol` instead of `twocolumn` and the problem is the same.

Comment: @egreg, you are right. do i change question title in mwe accordingly (that they will better describe the problem)?

Comment: I think you should.

Comment: In the meantime, I added a `\the` to the code that simplifies what's written in the `.aux` file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{linegoal}

\begin{document}

aaaa\the\linegoal

\vfill\pagebreak

aaaa\the\linegoal

\end{document}
```

outputs `aaaa147.27754pt` in the first column and `aaaa-90.55577pt` in the second one. The problem is that the position is computed in the same way for both columns.

A patch that works for your case (but that's admittedly not fully general): if the linegoal turns out to be negative, we add `\columnwidth+\columnsep`.

In the case above I get `aaaa147.27754pt` in both cases. With your example

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{linegoal}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\let\Z@E@linegoal\relax % undefine the property
\zref@newprop*{linegoal}[\linewidth]{%
   \the\dimexpr
   \ifdim\dimexpr
     \linewidth -\the\pdflastxpos sp
     +\ifodd\zref@extractdefault{linegoal/posx.\the\LNGL@unique}{page}\c@page
        \oddsidemargin
     \else\evensidemargin
     \fi
     +1in+\hoffset\relax<0pt
   \columnwidth+\columnsep+\fi
   \linewidth -\the\pdflastxpos sp
   +\ifodd\zref@extractdefault{linegoal/posx.\the\LNGL@unique}{page}\c@page
      \oddsidemargin
   \else\evensidemargin
   \fi
   +1in+\hoffset
   \relax
}% linegoal zref-property
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
NUP_S
    & =1- \rlap{\parbox[t]{\linegoal}{probability of successfully finishing an SU service}}\\[1ex]
    & = 1 - \frac{\lambda_S(1-P^{BL}_S)(1-P^{FT}_S)}{\lambda_S}\\
    & = P^{BL}_S + P^{FT}_S + P^{BL}_S  P^{FT}_S\\
NUP_S
    & = P^{BL}_S + P^{FT}_S - P^{BL}_S  P^{FT}_S
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2-3]
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
NUP_S
    & =1- \rlap{\parbox[t]{\linegoal}{probability of successfully finishing an SU service}}\\[1ex]
    & = 1 - \frac{\lambda_S(1-P^{BL}_S)(1-P^{FT}_S)}{\lambda_S}\\
    & = P^{BL}_S + P^{FT}_S + P^{BL}_S  P^{FT}_S\\
NUP_S
    & = P^{BL}_S + P^{FT}_S - P^{BL}_S  P^{FT}_S
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[4-5]
\end{document}
```

we get

[image]