# How can I use \linegoal properly inside minipages?

Tags: spacing, minipage, linegoal

I'm using `\linegoal` from the linegoal package to determine the remaining space on the current line. While this normally works perfectly, it seems to fail inside minipages. More concretely, it seems the value of `\linegoal` is reduced by any space in front of the minipage. This problem seems to be related (maybe the same source?) to the problem in this question: [\linegoal: its use in the second column of the two column document doesn't work correctly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484030/linegoal-its-use-in-the-second-column-of-the-two-column-document-doesnt-work)
The answer to that question, however, seems to be not applicable to minipages.

To make the issue concrete: I expect that `\linegoal` is equal to `\linewidth` at the beginning of the line. The following example shows that this is not the case inside a minipage that does not start at the very left of the page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{linegoal}

\begin{document}
    Linegoal works correctly in minipage starting on the left:

    \begin{minipage}{100pt}
        \rule{\linewidth}{1pt}

        \rule{\linegoal}{1pt}
    \end{minipage}

    Linegoal is reduced by space before minipage:

    \hspace{50pt}\begin{minipage}{100pt}
        \rule{\linewidth}{1pt}

        \rule{\linegoal}{1pt}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

This example produces the following output:
[image: Output of example]

Am I using this incorrectly or is this a bug in `\linegoal`? Is there a way to fix this issue to get correct measurements inside minipages (maybe using another package instead of linegoal)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe linegoal uses `\pdfsavepos`, which relates to the position on the overall page, and tries to calculate the position on the line based on that.

I'll suggest using tabto.sty with the odd construct

```
\tabto{\CurrentLineWidth}\rule{\dimexpr\linewidth-\TabPrevPos\relax}{1pt}
```

It seems silly, but the `\tabto` has the effect of measuring the line-so-far; and by tabbing to the same position there is no horizontal spacing, and the (same) position is saved as `\TabPrevPos`.

The material before the tab is typeset unstretched, which is different from how \linegoal works. This is a mixed blessing/curse. The bad (and ugly) is that text on either side of a tab may be unevenly stretched and look bad. The good is that the tab position is stable -- there is no attempt to record the position from one run and use it on the next run, which can lead \linegoal into endless loops of adjustment.

Sorry, there is no simple way to drop it into any old length argument. In an extension of your test, it not only fixes the offset minipage, but does a better job of sharing a line with preceding text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{linegoal}
\usepackage{tabto}

\begin{document}
    Linegoal works correctly in minipage starting on the left:

    \begin{minipage}{100pt}
        \rule{\linewidth}{1pt}

        \rule{\linegoal}{1pt} and after text \rule{\linegoal}{1pt}
    \end{minipage}

\bigskip
    Linegoal is reduced by space before minipage:

    \hspace{50pt}\begin{minipage}{100pt}
        \rule{\linewidth}{1pt}

        \rule{\linegoal}{1pt} and after text \rule{\linegoal}{1pt}
    \end{minipage}
    
\bigskip

    Try with tabto

    \begin{minipage}{100pt}
        \rule{\linewidth}{1pt}

        \tabto{\CurrentLineWidth}\rule{\dimexpr\linewidth-\TabPrevPos\relax}{1pt}
        and after text \tabto{\CurrentLineWidth}\rule{\dimexpr\linewidth-\TabPrevPos\relax}{1pt}
    \end{minipage}

\bigskip

    tabto with space before minipage:

    \hspace{50pt}\begin{minipage}{100pt}
        \rule{\linewidth}{1pt}

        \tabto{\CurrentLineWidth}\rule{\dimexpr\linewidth-\TabPrevPos\relax}{1pt}
        and after text \tabto{\CurrentLineWidth}\rule{\dimexpr\linewidth-\TabPrevPos\relax}{1pt}
    \end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `\tabto{\CurrentLineWidth}` in the example? If I just use `\rule{\dimexpr\linewidth-\CurrentLineWidth\relax}{1pt}`, the line after the text breaks up the line, but I don't understand why since tabbing to the current position should do nothing!?

Comment: Explanation added to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that uses `zref-abspos` package directly and LaTeX2e paragraph hook `para/begin` (provided in LaTeX2e 2021-06-01 or newer).  The line goal is then computed as the difference between x-coordinates of two `zref` positions, one at line start and one at current position.

Usage:

- Add `\markLineStart{<name>}` before or at the start of a paragraph.
  Currently it works by executing code at the start of the next paragraph, thus won't give correct result if `\parshape` is non-trivial.  Ideally the code should be executed at the start of a line, not paragraph.
- In the middle of some line (not necessarily the next paragraph after `\markLineStart{<name>}`), use `\getLineGoal{<name>}` to store the current line goal for `<name>` in `\xlinegoal`.  `\xlinegoal` is a macro starting with `\dimexpr`, hence it works like a dimension.  The internal calculation assumes the current line starts at the same x-coordinate as the first paragraph after `\markLineStart{<name>}`.
- Use `\getLineGoal[\cmd]{<name>}` to store line goal in `\cmd` other than `\xlinegoal`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{zref-abspos}

\makeatletter
\IfFormatAtLeastTF{2021-06-01}{% to use hook "para/begin"
  \newcounter{xlinegoal}
  \newcommand{\markLineStart}[1]{%
    \AddToHookNext{para/begin}{\zsaveposx{xlinegoal@#1}}%
    \ignorespaces
  }
  \newcommand{\getLineGoal}[2][\xlinegoal]{%
    \stepcounter{xlinegoal}%
    \zsaveposx{xlinegoal@#2@\the\c@xlinegoal}%
    \edef#1{\noexpand\dimexpr\the\dimexpr\linewidth+\zposx{xlinegoal@#2}sp-\zposx{xlinegoal@#2@\the\c@xlinegoal}sp\relax}%
    \ignorespaces
  }
}{\PackageError{xlinegoal}{LaTeX2e 2021-06-01 or newer is needed}{}}

\makeatother

% test helpers
\newcounter{testXLG}
\def\testXLineGoal{%
  \stepcounter{testXLG}
  X\hfill X
  
  \markLineStart{\arabic{testXLG}}
  text\nobreakspace
  \getLineGoal{\arabic{testXLG}}
  \rlap{\the\xlinegoal}\rule{\xlinegoal}{.4pt}%
}

\begin{document}
X\hfill X

\markLineStart{normal para}
some text \getLineGoal{normal para}\rule{\xlinegoal}{.4pt}
\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{100pt}
  \lipsum[1][1-3]
  
  \testXLineGoal
\end{minipage}
\qquad\begin{minipage}{100pt}
  \lipsum[1][1-3]
  
  \testXLineGoal
\end{minipage}%
\qquad\begin{minipage}{100pt}
  \lipsum[1][1-3]
  
  \testXLineGoal
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]